# How to create CRA-project without PWA features?

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I don't need PWA features in current project. How i can disable it?

I read the docs of CRA, delete `service-Worker.js` in `src` folder, but i can't exclude manifest file and `service-worker.js` in build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove:

- `<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />` from `public/index.html`
- `serviceWorker.unregister();` or `serviceWorker.register();` from `src/index.js`

Remember to unregister the SW before removing it, so the browser detach it from your domain.

Comment: but service-worker.js will be still be in `build` folder

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't be registered anymore. Assuming you unregistered it before..